# Magento multiple login options

Tags: magento-1.9

We have a store that needs to accept 2 options for customer login.

1. The traditional way - email / pw
2. First name / last name / pw

We have an extension that allows for #2, but we also need to accommodate for #1.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

It is for sure possible. It has to be implemented as extension. Details depend on custom code of #2 and Customer Configuration.